# Inequality problem involving sine function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, problem-solving

How can I prove the following inequality
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\bigg|\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\bigg|\,dx\geq\frac{2}{\pi}(1+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$$
Where $n \in\mathbb{N}$.
I have tried to use the given theorem
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)g(x)\,dx=f(c)\int_{a}^{b}g(x)\,dx$$ where $ c \in (a,b).$

After putting $c=\frac{\pi}{2}$ I am able to get $\frac{2}{\pi}$ coefficient in the right-hand side but after that I am unable to deduce the summation part of the given problem. How can I deduce any summation in the given problem? Also, if there is any other way to prove the problem, please explain it.

Comment: I don't think the mean value theorem is going to help you. You will want to split the bounds of integration into little pieces such as $[\pi/n,2\pi/n]$

Comment: I am unable to get any hint by splitting the bounds into smaller piece. Please, will you give any further hint to approach the problem.

Comment: Please, could you stop suggesting the same edits to my post? The edit suggestions you have made are more about personal taste than actual improvement. I personally dislike the common abuse beginners make, where $\sin(x)$ and $\sin$ are thought to be the same thing. $|\sin |$ is (denotes) a function, $|\sin(x)|$ is not. I've written things this way for a reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note
$$ [0,\pi]=\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1}\bigg[\frac{k\pi}n,\frac{(k+1)\pi}n\bigg]$$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_{0}^{\pi}\bigg|\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\bigg|\,dx\\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{\frac{k\pi}n}^{\frac{(k+1)\pi}n}\bigg|\frac{\sin(nx)}{x}\bigg|\,dx\\
&\overset{n(x-\frac{k\pi}n)\to x}=&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\bigg|\frac{\sin(x)}{x+k\pi}\bigg|\,dx\ge\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\sin(x)}{(k+1)\pi}\,dx\\
&\geq&\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{2}{(k+1)\pi}=\frac{2}{\pi}(1+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 2):

Some hints:

- $\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin=1$
- $\int_0^\pi=\sum_{j=1}^n\int_{p_{j-1}}^{p_j}$ for any partition $0=p_0<p_1<\cdots<p_{n-1}<p_n=\pi$ of $[0,\pi]$
- Try graphing $|\sin|$ and note the symmetries there
- On an interval $[a,b]$, with $a>0$, what can we say about $\min_{x\in[a,b]}\frac{1}{x}$?

*It might help to figure out the cases $n=1,n=2,n=3$ first before you see how to do this in general*. Alternatively, consider $u=nx$ and go for induction.